# difference between file.css.scss and file.scss (Rails)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I've been studying Rails recently and got stuck with a question. Is there any difference in creating file.scss and file.css.scss? I'm using rails -v 4.2.4

Answer (score 0):

I believe `file.css.scss` is auto generated after running `rails generate` when you create a new controller. Give [this](http://www.mattboldt.com/organizing-css-and-sass-rails/) short blog post a read it can perhaps shed more light on your question as well as give some advice about keeping your application structure well organized.

Comment: even when I use rails g command it generates file.scss And I went with both names, and rails works fine with both of them. I was just curious about significant differences between those two file names. Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any difference in creating `file.scss` and `file.css.scss`

Not in my experience.

Same goes for `.js.coffee` (we just call `.coffee`)

You can just call them by their actual filename, and Sprockets deals with them properly.