# Difference between application.css.scss and application.scss

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I've always just renamed by `application.css` file to `application.scss`, the way it says to do in the [Bootstrap Sass gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) setup instructions. But I almost never see it done that way anywhere else, people say to rename to `application.css.scss`.

Is there are particular reason most people use that method over the other that I should know about, or is it just preference? Does it make a difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/33045521/2681997

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between `.css.scss` and `.scss`.

Some people argue that it's important to have the resulting file extension as part of the filename.

Example:

- `.css.scss`
- `.js.coffee`
- `.html.erb`
- `.js.erb`

A coworker of mine was adamant about this, where as my thinking was that it's only important for files where the resulting file can be many different types (i.e. `.erb`).

While SCSS and CoffeeScript can only generate CSS and JS respectively.